# Implementing a Debug-only Print-to-console in Matlab

Tags: matlab, debugging, logging

I would like to set a flag that determines whether or not debug-print statements actually print to the console:

```
s_verbose       = 1;

global DBG
if s_verbose
    DBG = @(varargin) fprintf(varargin);
else
    DBG = @(varargin) 1;  % need the 1  :|
end
```

However this fails:

```
>> DBG('42')
Error using fprintf
Invalid file identifier.
Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

>> fprintf('42')
42
```

Is there any clean way to accomplish this?

Comment: Where do you want to write the log?

Comment: To the Matlab console.

Comment: So, why didn't use from `display` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often use a utility function like this:

```
function vfprintf(verbose, varargin)
% VFPRINTF Display output optionally depending on the level of verbosity.
%
% VFPRINTF(TF, ARGS) passes the arguments ARGS to the built-in MATLAB
% command |fprintf| if TF is logical true. If TF is logical false, VFPRINTF
% does nothing.

assert(islogical(verbose) && isscalar(verbose),...
    'utils:InvalidVerbose',...
    'VERBOSE must be logical true or false');

if verbose
    fprintf(varargin{:});
end
```

You can then call `vfprintf` instead of `fprintf`. Put your `verbose` variable as the first argument, with a value of `true` or `false`, and then follow with whatever arguments you would normally supply to `fprintf`. If `verbose` is `true`, it will display, but if `verbose` is `false`, it will do nothing.

PS - even if you do this, I would try to avoid making `verbose` a global variable if possible. It's not necessary.

Comment: So the thing I was missing was `{:}` after `varargin`. Thanks!